# Keywords that only exist in PL/pgSQL functions and DO blocks?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can we use SQL to find out which keywords only mean something to Postgres inside a [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) block or a [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) function? And if not, can somebody perhaps tell me whether my list is complete or if there are words that shouldn't be on this list:

> continue, exit, foreach, loop, return, return next, return query,
>   slice, while, alias, begin, constant, declare, exception, execute, get
>   (stacked) diagnostics, perform, raise, message, detail, hint, errcode,
>   debug, log, info, notice, warning, found, sqlerrm, sqlstate, new, old,
>   tg_name, tg_when, tg_level, tg_op, tg_relid, tg_relname,
>   tg_table_name, tg_table_schema, tg_nargs, tg_argv, tg_event, tg_tag

Comment: You can check your list again the list of [reserved keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: How is that list helping here? `foreach` for example can only be used in a function or do block and isn't on that list at all.

Comment: And `continue`can also only be used in a function or do block and is on the list.

Comment: So if it is on the list of reserved keywords, like `for`, it means it shouldn't be in your list

Comment: Do you have an example where Postgres uses `for` outside a function or do block?

Comment: No need for an example: the doc tells you not to use it as it has a special meaning

Comment: `... FOR UPDATE OF ...`  FOR is part of SQL *and* a keyword in plpgsql.

Comment: The question was, whether I can use SQL to find out which keywords just have a meaning to Postgres inside a function or do block. Or which words are missing or too much...

Comment: So, without my list, I don't have any keywords to check against the reserved words. And when every word currently not on my list, should only have a meaning inside a function or do block, I still cannot figure out whether my list is complete. But thanks for chiming in, @JGH... ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list in [`src/pl/plpgsql/src/pl_scanner.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/pl/plpgsql/src/pl_scanner.c;hb=HEAD):

Reserved keywords:

```
ALL
BEGIN
BY
CASE
DECLARE
ELSE
END
EXECUTE
FOR
FOREACH
FROM
IF
IN
INTO
LOOP
NOT
NULL
OR
STRICT
THEN
TO
USING
WHEN
WHILE
```

“Non-reserved” keywords:

```
ABSOLUTE
ALIAS
ARRAY
ASSERT
BACKWARD
CLOSE
COLLATE
COLUMN
COLUMN_NAME
CONSTANT
CONSTRAINT
CONSTRAINT_NAME
CONTINUE
CURRENT
CURSOR
DATATYPE
DEBUG
DEFAULT
DETAIL
DIAGNOSTICS
DUMP
ELSEIF
ELSIF
ERRCODE
ERROR
EXCEPTION
EXIT
FETCH
FIRST
FORWARD
GET
HINT
IMPORT
INFO
INSERT
IS
LAST
LOG
MESSAGE
MESSAGE_TEXT
MOVE
NEXT
NO
NOTICE
OPEN
OPTION
PERFORM
PG_CONTEXT
PG_DATATYPE_NAME
PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT
PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
PG_EXCEPTION_HINT
PRINT_STRICT_PARAMS
PRIOR
QUERY
RAISE
RELATIVE
RESULT_OID
RETURN
RETURNED_SQLSTATE
REVERSE
ROW_COUNT
ROWTYPE
SCHEMA
SCHEMA_NAME
SCROLL
SLICE
SQLSTATE
STACKED
TABLE
TABLE_NAME
TYPE
USE_COLUMN
USE_VARIABLE
VARIABLE_CONFLICT
WARNING
```

Special variables like `TG_RELID` or `FOUND` are not keywords, even though they play a special role in PL/pgSQL.